# Qt: Associating an array with a QTreeView item

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, treeview

I am trying to associate some data in the form of an array, say a column received from an sqlite database, with an item of my QTreeView, so that I can directly access that data from that item. For example, I can right click the item and select an action which would return the item's data for further manipulation like processing, plotting etc. So basically, I am trying to have a QTreeView item which represents an array of values.

QStandardItem::setData() doesn't seem to help me as it accepts a QVariant. I could try to somehow link a pointer, pointing to my data (array), to a QTreeView item and try to associate them but I am not sure if I need to spend my time for that. I checked the Qt documentation to see what I could do with views and models, however I could not find anything promising.

I am not after some sort of a QTableView application. I'm trying to represent a whole array by a single QTreeView item. I would appreciate any suggestions on this matter.

**Update:** I would like to state that I could work with Qt containers such as `QVector`, in case the answers may depend on the container type.

Comment: You need to register your container with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, than you may store it as `QVariant` inside you data model (not view) and use it. For example: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( QList< MyDataStruct > );`

Comment: Thank you for your input. I was planning to use `QVector` as my container so it would be easier since it's a native Qt type. [Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html) also say that `QVector` is automatically registered and doesn't need `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`. Now the point I don't really get is how I can pass a `QVector` while `QStandardItem::setData()` accepts a `QVariant`. I may be missing your point, I am sorry if that is the case.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things you can do. A QVariant can also be a QVariantList, so you can actually create a list of QVariant objects and store them using QStandardItem::setData. When setting the data, just create the QVariantList and pass it to setData. On retrieval, you'll get a QVariant, and then you call QVariant.toList() to convert that to a list that you can iterate through.

At that point, you have a QList of QVariant objects, so you have to convert the individual QVarient to whatever data type you're storing/retrieving.

When I used this technique, I wrapped the QVariant/QVariantList processing in a small class for simplicity.

You can also store a QVector directly into a QVariant. You have to use the "setValue" method to store the QVector and the "values" method to retrieve it:

```
typedef QVector <int> IntVector;
IntVector some_data;
QVariant variant;
variant.setValue (some_data);

IntVector result = variant.value <IntVector> ();
```

The typedef is there solely to clean up the code a little. Of course, you can use the QVector declaration directly.

Comment: Edited my previous comment, it was my bad. I was able to adapt this solution to my code. Thank you very much.